# How do I make knuckle joints sharper and more plump?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I know I asked a similar question like this before, but I didn't get much of a proper answer. How do I make the knuckle joints of my character's hand "fatter" as they bend downward and if possible make the top part more "pointed" all without using Drivers? Also my character's using subdivision modifier right now.[image: image of bend joint showing problem]

Comment: Check "Preserve Volume" on the armature. Move the joint upwards towards the knuckle.

Comment: also you could try to add a bone for the knuckle itself, or try to segment your bones: Bone panel > Bendy Bones > Segments

Comment: How do i preserve volume on my armature?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting technique, where the Mid bone is duplicated in edit mode. Switch the direction of the newly created corrective bone, make it child of the Mid, assign a rot constraint targeting the same Mid bone, with inverted XYZ, and assign some  weight on the knuckles vertices.

The influence slider lets you control the amount of the effect.

[image]

Comment: How do I make bone "child of" also do i have to tilt bone slightly up?

Comment: In edit mode select the child (can be more than one) last shift select the parent, Ctrl P > keep offset. In this set up the new bone can have any tilt, it doesn't matter, for clarity you can leave them one on the other.

Comment: Sorry to sound annoying but i forgot to ask do i assign the rot constraint to the mid bone or corrective bone?

Comment: To the corrective bone, but theese are basics, I think you should watch some basic tutorials to get in touch with rigging in general, like this, which is old but very good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ